# Find the extreme values of $f(x,y) = 3x^2 + 2y^2 -2x -5$ on the region $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I tried using Lagrange multipliers to find the extremum on the level curve of $x^2 + y^2 <= 1$ and I kept getting $x = 1$.
\begin{align}
f_x &= 6x - 2 &= \lambda 2x\\
f_y &= 4y &= \lambda 2y
\end{align}
So $\lambda=2$, $x = 1$, and $y = 0$. Plugging that into the equation yields $-4$, but that's not the absolute maximum? It has to be because the absolute minimum is $-16/3$, which I found by $6x-2 = 0$ and $4y = 0$?

Comment: No, it is not. Take $x=-1$, $y=0$, you get $f=0>-4$.

Comment: I know, but how would you get that answer without trial and error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: look carefully at the equation $4y=2\lambda y$. If $y=0$ then $\lambda$ does not have to be $2$ (and *vice versa*). It gives you some freedom.

Comment: If y = 0, lambda is still 2 because of the equation of the region.

Comment: @Goldname If $y=0$ then due to the constraint $x=\pm 1$ ($x^2+y^2=1$ on the boundary) and from the first equation you get two lamdbas. One for $x=1$ is indeed $2$, but for $x=-1$ it is different.

Comment: Ahhh! I see. Thank you